# Search API displays

Tags: search

I have added a Server and selected "Database Service" as the Service class then I add an Index and select the server I have created and then I select node and then when I save I have the Server Index Issue immediately.

I have tried clearing all indexed data as well as running cron, clear all caches and also restarted the server.

I have also tried a fresh drupal install with a new database.

I have also installed a fresh Drupal 7.43 and only added the search api, search api db and entity modules and the same problem is occurring.

I have also set this up on simplytest.me to see if I was doing something wrong but its works straight away.

Any suggestions would be appreciated as this is the last part needed for the project Im working on.enter image description here